# Window Builder in Eclipse (JAVA) Won't Load

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, windowbuilder

I'm in the process of learning JAVA and was looking for a GUI editor/creator for use within Eclipse. I Googled and found "WindowBuilder". I installed it via these instructions:

https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/wbpro/installation/

When I installed it, I checked each checkbox to install everything. However, when I create a class to create a GUI, and then I click on the "Design" tab, I get "This is not a GUI class and can't be edited graphically" (even though I chose an option for WindowBuilder when creating the class).

When I open classes that already contain (working) GUIs, I get "Unknown GUI Toolkit."

Is there a way to get WindowBuilder running, or perhaps is there a better solution?

Comment: With all due respect, that was not what I was asking. I was asking how to make Window Builder work, not how I should go about learning things. I have already learned how to lay out a GUI through code, but now I want to focus on an actual project and I want to test out Window Builder. Let's please focus on my question.

Answer (score 11):

For the record, I had the same problem but I forgot to install the "Swing Designer" module from the "Install New Software..." option in "Help" menu.

Comment: This is the 2nd time this answer has helped me in as many months, because I stupidly don't document little quirks like this. If I could upvote you a second time, I would!

Comment: @RTF I know exactly what you mean ;)

Answer (score 2):

Tab "Help"-> "Install New Software" .. in "Work with " , enter 
 Name : Kepler URL :  http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler and ADD

and on "type filter text" write "Swing Designer" . install that and you should be fine ..

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed. The JRE option in Eclipse properties was invalid. It pointed to JRE6 instead of JRE7. I'm not sure how Eclipse was ever working in the first place. All set. Thanks!